# Using PowerBI How can I return the correct grade if I have a table which has the lower and upper values for each grade

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a table with the final numeric value for each student in a class, using powerBI how would i convert that to a grade value (A+, B....F) if I have a table with the each grade and its upper and lower values e.g. A+, 80, 100 . So if the student got 82 then the grade would be A+, if it was 34, it would be something else

I don't want to expand out the table so I have 100 rows each with 1 grade value if I don't have to

Comment: could you make a calculated column then use the switch statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax >= 90 A, >= 80 B etc.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid hard coding the values and instead use them from a table

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific about your current model (tables/relationships etc).

Suppose we have two tables (without relationship)
[image]

[image]

I can calculate it like this :

```
GRADE = 
var __StudVal = SELECTEDVALUE(StudentExam[Value])
return

CALCULATE(min(Grades[Grade]), FILTER(ALL(Grades),__StudVal > Grades[Lband] && __StudVal <= Grades[Uband] ))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @msta42a When I use the calculated column I get no value returned though even its actually one of the upper band values exactly. Can you suggest how I could troubleshoot it?